# Calculate result without entering python shell

Tags: python, linux, shell

Is it possible to calculate an expression using python but without entering python shell? What I want to achieve is to use python in a following manner:

```
tail file.txt -n `python 123*456`
```

instead of having to calculate 123*456 in a separate step.

Comment: did you try >>> tail file.txt -n `python $((123*456))`

Comment: It returns `python: can't open file '/home/56088': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` so apparently it does the calculations but doesn't return the value

Comment: But `tail file.txt -n $((123*456))` works perfectly

Comment: Another shell variant : `n=\`echo 123*456 | bc\`;tail -n $n file.txt`

Comment: `tail file.txt -n "python $((123*456))"`

Comment: It is possible, but why do you even want to do that? There are much simpler, more performant ways. What are you actually trying to do? I don't mean *"I want to run Python"*, but rather *"I want to see some lines of a file starting from knowing xyz"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand your question: you say "I would like to do something using Python", but when you show what you want to do, Python seems not to be needed for achieving that.

Let me show you: what you want to achieve, can be done as follows:

```
tail -f file.txt -n $((123*456))
```

The `$((...))` notation is capable of performing integer calculations, as you can imagine.

Is this what you are looking for, or are you really forced to use Python, and if so, why do you think that?

Comment: When I was writing my question Python seemed the easiest solution for me, but I posted the example to demonstrate the exact problem I was facing in case there was even better solution that I wasn't aware of. So basically, your answer solves my problem :)

Comment: @mmichal10 If this answer solves your problem, you should consider accepting it (click ✅) and upvoting it (click ).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `-c` option. For e.g, `` tail test_log.txt -n `python -c "print(1 + 2)"` ``